# Debugging React Native IOS Version in Mac (NOT AN EXPO but react-native run-ios)

Tags: react-native, debugging, react-native-ios

My React Native app works properly on Android.  However for the iOS side/version of my React Native app, the SPLASH SCREEN shows up and gets stuck there.

I have put a `console.log` output on the `componentDidMount` of the First Screen of my App.
I have tried to use the SHAKE option on the iOS Simulator but for some reason the debug screen does not show up.

I would like to check why the app freezes but I don't even get any error showing on the simulator.  I'm guessing that there might a error/feedback from the system in the console output but I don't know how to go to the debugging screen where the console.log will show up when one runs `react-native run-ios`.

How to display the screen/console where the console.log("WHATEVER") I put on the code will display its output????

Comment: Have you tried to run the app from Xcode directly?

Comment: Hi I've tried running it in Xcode and I'm getting -> fatal error: module map file '/Users/user172159/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RNJyotish-blrkxmqcjcfzymeynmfauvzqlhng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found. However if I run react-native run-ios command it loads on the simulator but gets stuck on the splash screen

Comment: try to press cmd + control + z on the simulator to show the debug menu. 
Also regarding the prooblem on Xcode did you open the .xcodeworkspace?

Comment: cmd + control + z does not work for me.  However I'm looking at other solutions and I've tried turning on Developer menu on Safari...and then in the Developer Menu that shows up choose the JS CONTEXT of the SIMULATOR.  It is not reliable though...sometimes it shows up and sometimes it doesn't...when it doesn't and I accesss localhost:8081/debugger-ui I see status code 500 on the browser console...